# Display custom error message when user tries to edit a protected cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro to protect the first 7 rows. It displays a message box `"The cell or chart that you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only."` when user tries to edit the content. 
Belwo is the macro...

```
Function columnNumberToLetter(columnNumber As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, columnNumber).Address(True, False), "$")
    columnNumberToLetter = vArr(0)
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    Dim theFirtCellOfHeader As String
    Dim theLastCellOfHeader As String
    Dim headerRange As String

    Set sht = Sheets(1)
    theFirtCellOfHeader = "A1" 
    lastColumn = sht.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    theLastCellOfHeader = columnNumberToLetter(lastColumn) & 7
    headerRange = theFirtCellOfHeader & ":" & theLastCellOfHeader
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Cells.Locked = False
    Range(headerRange).Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

Is there a way to display the custom error message instead of the default message box?

Comment: could try data validation maybe.  it allows for custom error messages and 2nd or 3rd tab.

Comment: No, I cannot do that, since I am using this macro book to open a CSV file and in that CSV file I want to restrict the user from tampering the header.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code which will protect the first seven rows and display a custom error message:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim goodRng As Range
If Target.Locked Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheet1.Range(8 & ":" & 100).Locked = False 'set to desired unlocked rows
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Stop!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "The cell(s) you are trying to alter are protected" & vbNewLine & _
        "and should not be altered without prior" & vbNewLine & _
        "authorization." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Thank you," & vbNewLine & _
        "Management", vbCritical, "STOP!"
End If
End Sub
```

I can't take credit for the basis of the code, I adopted it from Zack Barresse @ MrExcel.com.  I just changed it to meet your purposes.

Note: I have unlocked rows 8-100, feel free to adjust how much of the sheet you want locked down (65536 is the maximum number of spreadsheet rows).

Hope it helps!

Comment: This will popup a message box when user clicks on the protected cell and it is quite annoying. I want the message box to be shown whenever user tries to edit it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood the requirement.  Let me think about how I could change it up and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

NJMR,

How about this?  Changed it from Selection to Change, and put an undo statement in so that it removes whatever changes the user entered and then gives the error.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim goodRng As Range
If Target.Locked Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Sheet1.Range(8 & ":" & 65536).Locked = False 'set to desired unlocked rows
    MsgBox "Stop!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "The cell(s) you are trying to alter are protected" & vbNewLine & _
    "and should not be altered without prior" & vbNewLine & _
    "authorization." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Thank you," & vbNewLine & _
    "Management", vbCritical, "STOP!"
End If
End Sub
```